# Assembly Loop Through Each Bit of Register Value

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I have a register $t0 that has some integer stored to it. For example, say I store the integer 1100 to it. The binary representation of this value is 0000010001001100. Of course it may extend to 32 bits for 32 bit register but that is easily done.

I am trying to implement a loop in assembly that iterates through each bit of the register value and checks if it is a 1 or 0. How would one do this?

Perhaps I misunderstand the nature of a register. It is my understanding that the register stores a 32 bit number, yes? Does that mean each bit is stored at a specific address?

I have tried using shift for the register and checking the bit but that has failed. I also looked into the lb command but this loads the byte, not the bit. So what would one do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any processor, set up a loop to count the number of bits in a register, in this case 32. On each pass through the loop, AND the register of interest with 1. Then add the result to an accumulator, and finally shift the register. That gives you the number of set bits.

The precise instructions vary from processor to processor. To loop you normally set a label, decrement a counter, then execute an instruction with a name like branch_not_equal_to zero (BNZ, BNEQ0 something like that). The and will have a name like AND, ANDI (and immediate). The ADD might be ADD, ADC (add with carry). The shift will be something like ASR (arithmetic shift right) LSR (logical shift right), you might have to pass it 1 to say shift only one place. But all processors will allow you to read out register bits in essentially this way.

Comment: @Malcom McLean what does the AND do? EDIT: I have edited the question. I meant to ask what AND does not ADD I apologize

Comment: Adds two numbers together. usually two registers.

Comment: @Malcom McLean I have edited my comment please take a look

Comment: AND means that 0 0 = 1, 1,0 = 0, 0,1 = 0, 1,1 = 1. So you only get a 1 if a and b are both 1. You do the operation for each bit in a register. One important use is to mask off bits. Here we AND with 1 to get only the last bit. r1 = r2 AND 1 sets r1 to 0 iif the last bit of r2 is clear, 1 if it is set. All the other bits must be zero.

Comment: Are there any tutorials/links you recommend to understand assembly better? I understand what AND (I understand using AND to check each bit, but not what you meant by AND to get only the last bit...) does but I got lost in its application as you mentioned. I believe this is moreso due to my novice understanding of assembly rather than your explanation. Still, your help was appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a good link for assembly programming. I learnt from Machine Code on your ZX81 by Toni Baker, but it;s unlikely you'll have a ZX81 these days.

Comment: there's no need to know the size of the register (32 bit), just loop until your target register's content is 0, this way you also don't need any counter

Answer (score 4):

some basics:

most(all?) shift instructions shift out the bit into the carry flag

most(all?) CPUs have a branch command, to jump to the location on carry flag set

combining this, you could do the following:

```
load register1,< the value to be tested >
load register2, 0

Lrepeat:
    compare register1 with 0
    jump if zero Lexit

    shift right register1
    jump no carry Lskip
    increase register2 
Lskip:
    jump Lrepeat

Lexit:                      ; when you end up here, your register2
                            ; holds the count of bit register1 had set
```

some optimization still can be done:

```
Lrepeat:
    compare register1 with 0
    jump if zero Lexit
    shift right register1
    jump no carry Lskip       <-- note: here you jump ...
    increase register2 
Lskip:
    jump Lrepeat              <-- ... to jump again!
Lexit:

=====>

Lrepeat:
    compare register1 with 0
    jump if zero Lexit
    shift right register1
    jump no carry Lrepeat     <-- so you can optimize it this way
    increase register2 
Lskip:
    jump Lrepeat             
Lexit:
```

some CPUs have an "add carry" instuction,
e.g. 6502:

```
ADC register,value      ; register = register + value + Carry flag
```

this could be used to avoid the branch (conditional jump), by adding 0 ( plus Carry of course) to register2 each loop

```
    shift right register1
    add with carry register2,0   ; may look weird, but this adds a 
                                 ; 1 if the carry is set, which is
                                 ; exactly what we want here
    jump Lrepeat
```

note that you don't need to know the register size! you just loop until the register is 1, which can save you a lot of time e.g. if your value is something like 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1001

Comment: I am using MIPS. This does not seem to have a carry flag? Right? Or am I missing something. 
Also, under the loop Lrepeat you say "compare register1 with 0". If register 1 has some value (say 1450, converted to binary of course), what value is the register comparing to 0? I assume the point of this is to find the 1's, but then how would that work?

Comment: oh, I think you mix something, and I wasn't clear enough. "jump if zero" <-- here the zero FLAG is checked. Lrepeat is the label used in checking if all 1 bits inside the value have been counted (and shiftet out). once this is the case, the register contains 0.and the loop can be stopped, so that's why the value is compared to 0 there

Comment: MIPS doesn't have flags.  It has instructions like `BEQ reg1, reg2, target`, or `BGEZ reg, target` to compare for greater than zero and branch.  http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html.  So I guess you'd `andi $t0, $t1, 0x1` to set $t0 = the low bit of $t1, and then you could branch on that.  (There's an architectural zero-register, so you can `beq $t0, $0, low_bit_zero`)

Answer (score 0):

Have the register that you want to iterate through be denoted as R0. So, for example, the least significant bits are `R0= 1011 0101`.

2) use a second cleared register `R1=0000 0001`.

3) `AND` `R1` with `R0` and then right shift `R0`(so the next iteration checks the next bit of `R0`).

4) Let `R3` be a third register that increments by 1  `IF` the `AND` operation results in a 1 (that is, you run into a 1 in `R0`). `ELSE`, loop again to check the next bit in `R0`.

You could iterate through the entire 32 bits or a length of your choice by having a decrementing loop counter .